# Apply css for <html> when click on button in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to show hidden scrollbar for whole page.But when I click on button it went to next page and scrollbar should be visible.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftdwez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS overflow property on condition.

As per stackbliz example

```
<p style="overflow:hidden"></p>
```

User hidden on default and when click on make it

```
overflow:scroll
```

Use,

```
[ngClass]="step == 'step1' ? 'my_class1' : 'my_class2'"
```